# Dispatching an action every second with redux-observable

Tags: react-native, rxjs, rxjs6, redux-observable

With plain `Rxjs`, I managed to implement a "countdown" behavior by invoking a method each second like this, until there's no more time left:

```
const time = 5 
var timer$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000) 
timer$
  .take(time)
  .map((v)=> {
           const remaining = time - 1 - v
           return remaining; 
      })
  .subscribe((v)=>console.log('Countdown', v))
```

Now, with `redux-observable`, I want to implement a countdown behavior, where I get the initial time (e.g 5000 seconds) and I dispatch an action each second until the initial time is down to 0. So far I have this:

```
action$.pipe(
        ofType(START_COUNTDOWN),
        switchMap(() =>
            interval(1000)
                .map((time) => updateTime(time))),
);
```

But I'm getting an error: `Property map does not exist on type Observable<Number>`. What am I don't wrong here, because I feel that it shouldn't be very hard to accomplish this with `redux-observable`.

Comment: In your `redux-observable` app you're using newer version of RxJS (> 6.0) that supports only pipable operators while you're trying to use the old "patch" style. So you should use `interval(1000).pipe(map(...))`.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: @martin yes, that was it. Can you add an answer with some more details so I accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `redux-observable` app you're using the newer version of RxJS (> 6.0) that supports only pipable operators while you're trying to use the old "patch" style (there's also `rxjs-compat` package for backwards compatibility, but that's recommended only to support older code). So since RxJS 6 you should only use `pipe()`:

```
action$.pipe(
  ofType(START_COUNTDOWN),
  switchMap(() => interval(1000).pipe(
    map((time) => updateTime(time))
  )),
);
```